# Testing Values in a Dictionary with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dictionary, jasmine, automated-tests

I am unit testing my email checking function. I tried writing a dictionary of test string, description, and expected results and executing tests with for loops but it did not work. 
Now, I am making changes to my spec file one by one to see where it is getting wrong.

```
describe("Email", function() {
  var email;

  beforeEach(function() {
    email = undefined;
    console.log('new test');
  });

 it("should reject undefined", function() {
    console.log('test 0');
    email = undefined;
    console.log(email);
    expect(checkEmail(email)).toEqual({'result':false});
  });

 it("should reject numbers", function() {
    console.log('test 1');
    email = 123456;
    console.log(email);
    expect(checkEmail(email)).toEqual({'result':false});
  });
});
```

This works.

```
describe("Email", function() {
  var email;
  **var emails = [undefined, 123456];**

  beforeEach(function() {
    email = undefined;
    console.log('new test');
  });

 it("should reject undefined", function() {
    console.log('test 1');
    **email = emails[0];**
    console.log(email);
    expect(checkEmail(email)).toEqual({'result':false});
  });

 it("should reject numbers", function() {
    console.log('test 2');
    **email = emails[1];**
    console.log(email);
    expect(checkEmail(email)).toEqual({'result':false});
  });
});
```

This works.

```
describe("Email", function() {
  var email;
  **var tests = {{'email':undefined}, {'email':123456}};**

  beforeEach(function() {
    email = undefined;
    console.log('new test');
  });

 it("should reject undefined", function() {
    console.log('test 1');
    **email = tests[0].email;**
    console.log(email);
    expect(checkEmail(email)).toEqual({'result':false});
  });

 it("should reject numbers", function() {
    console.log('test 2');
    **email = tests[1].email;**
    console.log(email);
    expect(checkEmail(email)).toEqual({'result':false});
  });
});
```

This does not work. Why?

Comment: Meanwhile, I am programmatically writing this spec file with Python.

Comment: You spelled `undefined` wrong in your top code block. Also, it's not clear what is not working from your post.

Comment: @seth-flowers Bold style is not working. In the third example, my test values are in a dictionary. And, suddenly, I cannot run this test any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your "dictionary" incorrectly.

Change this:

```
var tests = {{'email':undefined}, {'email':123456}}
```

to either of the following:

```
var tests = [{'email':undefined}, {'email':123456}];
var tests = {0: {'email':undefined}, 1: {'email':123456}};
```